# Using Linq to select Place object with Tag.Name = "Restaurant" (many to many)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

asp.net MVC 4 app - linq to objects with many to many relationship

Place object

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

Tag object

```
  public virtual int TagID { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual string NamePlural { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

I'm new to Linq - and need a statement to select all places with the related tag "restaurant". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
//List<Place> allPlaces = initialized to the initial list
List<Place> list = allPlaces.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == "restaurant")).ToList();
```